# Gatsby Build failed because of "Unknown Word' Error from CSS minimzer on postcss and css-minimizer-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

My Gatsby.js site runs without error when I use 'gatsby develop' but the build always fails returning the following error when I 'gatsby build':

`
Generating JavaScript bundles failed

```
styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css:756:5
: Unknown word [styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css:756,5]
at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\post
css\lib\input.js:123:16)
at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modul
es\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\pos
tcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\pos
tcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\postcss\li
b\parse.js:11:12)
at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\p
ostcss\lib\lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_module
s\postcss\lib\processor.js:36:12)
at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform
(C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\css
-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), :51:61)
at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\gatsby\no
de_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
at Object.transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules
\gatsby\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

File: styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css
```

`
Link to reproduced github:

https://github.com/Dahbu7/gatsby-issue-1

I have uninstalled postcss and postcss-loader and reinstalled them as dev dependencies - that didn't work
I have uninstalled css-minimizer-webpack-plugin and reinstalled it as dev dependency - that didn't work either.

PLEASE NOTE: After I uninstalled just postcss I ran build again so it could use the postcss package that is in the node_modules/gatsby folder as in, node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/postcss and that didn't work either.

My Node version is: v14.15.0
My dev-dependency installed webpack version is:
Everything else can be found in the github light reproduction repo:

https://github.com/Dahbu7/gatsby-issue-1

I tried hosting it on gatsby cloud and the deploy build failed there too for the exact same reason. I even did the NODE_VERSION = 16 thing as an environment variable and that didn't work. Please try it again though. Maybe I did it wrong.

I have done several react projects but this is my first time converting over to Gatsby. Any help woud be greatly appreciated.

Reproduction Link
https://github.com/Dahbu7/gatsby-issue-1

Steps to Reproduce
Go to the repo I posted: https://github.com/Dahbu7/gatsby-issue-1
You can run gatsby build on your system or any platform of your choice.
Node Version is v14.15.0
...
Expected Result
Javascript bundles of node modules should build without error when 'gatsby build' is ran. It builds properly with 'gatsby develop'.

Actual Result

```
failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 116.946s

ERROR #98123 WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css from Css Minimizer
C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css:756:5
: Unknown word [styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css:756,5]
at Input.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\post
css\lib\input.js:123:16)
at Parser.unknownWord (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modul
es\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
at Parser.other (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\pos
tcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
at Parser.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\pos
tcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\postcss\li
b\parse.js:11:12)
at new LazyResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\p
ostcss\lib\lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_module
s\postcss\lib\processor.js:36:12)
at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform
(C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\css
-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), :51:61)
at minify (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules\gatsby\no
de_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
at Object.transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\gatsby-troubleshoot-positiveo\node_modules
\gatsby\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

File: styles.1a4684d19cee467a516a.css

Environment
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3340M CPU @ 2.70GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.11 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.8 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 94.0.4606.71
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1023.0), Chromium (94.0.992.38)
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^3.13.1 => 3.14.2
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^1.14.1 => 1.14.1
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^3.14.0 => 3.14.0
    gatsby-plugin-postcss: ^4.14.0 => 4.14.0
    gatsby-plugin-preconnect: ^1.2.1 => 1.2.1
    gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts: ^2.14.0 => 2.14.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^4.14.0 => 4.14.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-svg: ^3.0.1 => 3.0.1
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^3.14.1 => 3.14.1
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^4.10.0 => 4.10.0
    gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader: ^1.0.4 => 1.0.4
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^3.14.0 => 3.14.0
    gatsby-theme-material-ui: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^3.14.0 => 3.14.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 3.14.0
```

Comment: The link 「https://github.com/Dahbu7/gatsby-issue-1」 is 404

Comment: @JohnHou did you find a solution to this? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Check out this link to the issue on github https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/33474. I think they came up with a solution. What we we all had in common was we were using the slick-carousel package. Go read what they said  on the issue thread

Comment: I've had a problem with dynamic string in the tailwind classNames when using the tailwind postcss plugin. Tailwind plugin takes plain strings from from classes and generates the css for it, so if you have `"max-w-[${MAX_CONST}]"` as a className - it will generate a broken css.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not with postcss or anything else, its the bundler you are using which in case seems to be Webpack. What you need to do is to go into your webpack config file, find out where css is minimized, probably where you are using `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` and then the output must be like `[name].[contentHash].css` just rename it to `[name].css`. That should work

Comment: Thank you for your response but I believe the issue was specific to a package call 'slick-carousel' . We had to set up scss processing or delete the package and use their CDN links instead. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/33474